# send form data using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How can send data this input for php code without use button:submit(with use of tag `<a href=""></a>`) as that after it go to href and put row of $query in html code for update?

(i mean, after select checkbox and click on link in tag  send value with jquery code to php code and go to link tag a for update)(i dont want to use `action` in tag form because i use from several url for `action`) How fix it?

HTML:

```
<a href="<?= base_url()?>submits/guide_update" class="guide_update" id="edit_icon"></a>
<form class="ser_form" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="2">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function guide_update(){
$update = $this -> input -> post('checked');
var_dump($update);
if (is_array($update) && count($update) > 0) {
    foreach($update as $val){
        $data['query'] = $this->db->get_where('guide', array('id' => $val))->row();
    }
    $this -> load -> view('admin/submits/guide_update', $data);
}
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#edit_icon').click(function(){
    var result = true;
        var size_check = $(':checkbox:checked').size();
        //alert(size_check);
        if(size_check > 1){
            $('#message').hide().fadeIn('slow').html('<div id="error_text" style="background-color: #ffffd9; border: 1px solid #d2d200;">You're allowed to edit a row.<div>');
            $('#error_text').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow');
            result = false;
        }if(size_check == 0){
            //alert('no')
            $('#message').hide().fadeIn('slow').html('<div id="error_text" style="background-color: #ffffd9; border: 1px solid #d2d200;">You did not select any row for editing.<div>');
            $('#error_text').delay(7000).fadeOut('slow');
            result = false;
        }
    return result 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [JQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to serialize form data, which you can then send to the server using AJAX.

Comment: In your code on click function write       var form_params = $(".ser_form").serialize() and then send this form_params in the ajax call.

Comment: I have this output in var_dump:`bool(false)` , i put as: `$('#edit_icon').click(function(){$(".ser_form").serialize()...`